# How can i make date and time picked to be displayed as it is disappearing

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

In Flutter, I have used dateTimePicker in my code for date of birth filed , i am able to select the date but after selecting it shows that particular date only for some time, after that it is back to the current date , how do i make it to show the date i selected.
here is my code,

`Card(
color: Colors.blue[50],
margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5, right: 20),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 1),
),
child: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(
left: 30, top: 5, right: 30, bottom: 10),
child: DateTimePicker(
validator: (val) => val == null
? "Please pick date of birth"
: null,
cursorColor: Color(0xFF75101D),
type: DateTimePickerType.date,
dateMask: 'dd MMMM yyyy',
initialValue: dob,
lastDate: DateTime(2100),
icon: Icon(Icons.event),
dateLabelText: 'Date of Birth',
onChanged: (val) {
var localDate = DateTime.parse(val);

```
                            var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
                            var formatted = formatter.format(localDate);
                            print(formatted);
                            setState(() {
                              dob = formatted;

                              print(dob);
                            });
                          },
                          firstDate: DateTime(1950),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),`
```

Comment: You should share your code to help us understand what's your problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.